# separation of concerns between Service and Repository for a multi-step database operation

Tags: php, asp.net, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

Consider the **differences** in the following two examples of a User Service (*here I'm using PHP but the question can apply to any language*):
Example 1:

```
class UserService {

    public function save($id, $data)
    {
        UserRepository::save($id, $data);  // Updates user and user history, etc
    }
}
```

Example 2:

```
class UserService {

    public function save($id, $data)
    {
        UserRepository::save($id, $data);        // Updates user
        UserRepository::saveHistory($id, $data);  // Updates user history
        etc...
    }
}
```

This is a simple example, but it can become difficult in a project to know when we are dealing with "business concerns" as opposed to "data persistence concerns" (I apologize if I'm not using the correct terminology here). **In regard to proper SoC with Services and Repositories, are both of these perfectly acceptable ways of using the Repository Pattern? How do we know when to use one over the other?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not about the pattern. It's about the responsibilities. Does a `save()` always mean `save current` and `save history`. Because if does, the first way is better, but the background is important. You should have two model methods for save and savehistory and what logic repository that groups them.

The second variant is wrong not because of pattern way, but because of lack of checks.

I don't know what does `save` and `saveHistory` should mean exactly, but let's say you have `users` table where you store user information including the last login. And `user_login_history` where you save each login.

In this case `save()` will try to insert the current timestamp for users lastlogin. But what if it fails? In some circumstances the `save()` method return false. A momental lack of db connection, timeout, wrong datatypes, etc. But the method returns non-true value. The execution of `UserServices::save()` will continue after exiting from `Repository::save()`, and then will go to `saveHistory()` and will add login_history for this user with the current timestamp, even your user was not able to login. So you will have false data.

If you want to use the second way, do the proper checks. The simpliest way is:

```
public function save($id, $data)
{
    if(UserRepository::save($id, $data)) {        // Updates user
        UserRepository::saveHistory($id, $data);  // Updates user history
        ... // etc related method based on successful save()
    }
}
```

Ensure for the right execution of the methods, but stick to the single responsibility.

Comment: Yeah, I realized the second example needed some sort of return before executing the next call to UserRepository::saveHistory...but I just wanted to get my point across ASAP.

Comment: So you are saying that each example DOES follow the pattern properly? And its up to my discretion on whether tasks should be more in the repository as opposed to the services? I suppose I'm wondering which tends to be "fatter" when dealing with multiple database calls to fully persist something?

Comment: You are breaking the single responsibility if save and saveHistory do two total different things. In this case the first example does not really follow the pattern. Thus, the second example plus additional checks is the better one.

Comment: That's what I was feeling. Because if I'm smart, then I can create my services in such as way that I can call a specific service to perform both the calls to User and User History when I want both persisted, as opposed to only one.

Comment: It's also helpful to remember that repositories are "services" in some ways. So I shouldn't feel too guilty "fattening" them up, but probably only in extreme circumstances when the services will NEVER need to touch the parts I'm adding to the Repo aggregate.

Comment: Nothing to feel guilty of. A design pattern is paradigm, not a law. You are not obligated to obey rules. You use them to solve problems :) That's why they are useful. You just need to make your life easier. And maybe if you fatter a repo just to use it in the Service this way, you might have hard time later :) As I said in the beginning, it depends on how one is dependent to another :)

Comment: I find the second example completely ok. It should throw exception and so avoid executing consecutive actions if save() fails. If you considered at 'command-query separation' rule then you save() should not returned anything. read more on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation

Answer (score 1):

The above example is breaking the Single Responsibility Principle. UserRepository should be taking care only of User persistence. History would be usually stored in some "history table" hence the HistoryService. I could imagine it would need some extra logic than just persistence (eg. extracting changed data from entity ...)

Such HistoryService object (we used to call it AuditService) would be injected into the Repository in Dependency Injection Container. The code could look like this:

```
class UserService {

    private $historyService;

    public function __construct(HistoryService $historyService)
    {
        $this->historyService = $historyService;
    }

    public function save($id, $data)
    {
        UserRepository::save($id, $data);        // Updates user
        $this->historyService->saveHistory('user', $id, $data);  // Updates user history
        etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: Single Responsibility and Separation of Concerns can be very subjective. That's part of the reason for my question. I mean, one can create a 100 classes of code that are then grouped into 1 class and all you ever call is that 1 class. So the 100 classes are just sitting out there, unused and adding to the growing list of classes that make up a project. I know this can make it easier to test each "part", but one has to be careful it seems to not make the code "too modular" where there is this bloat of classes that quickly becomes difficult to find anything (and to avoid accidentally rewriting).

Comment: So it seems I need to look for proper "grouping" of concerns that truly can represent a unique whole concern as group. If I separate too prematurely, it can be very wasteful. But, this does bring a point across about why I'm starting to think the Repository Pattern can be a **[problem](http://tech.pro/blog/1191/say-no-to-the-repository-pattern-in-your-dal)**. It seems to turn all my dynamic queries into a huge growing list of methods. And I also lose (or leak) the advantages of working with a specific database technology.

Comment: And if I make my Repository methods more flexible, then I really do start to experience methods that are too complex and it screams "Single Responsibility problem".

Comment: I gave you +1, because you showed another way to attack the problem. However, make sure you take a look at the criticism and the pitfalls of the Repository Design Pattern, before diving completely in.

Comment: And check out what Jimmy Boggard writes **[here](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/09/20/limiting-your-abstractions/)** and **[here](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/10/08/favor-query-objects-over-repositories/)**

Comment: I dont think that Khalid Abuhakmeh understands the concept of repository (eg. there is no update() or save() methods - unit of work should take of that). Furthermore "100 classes sitting around" - the goal of OOD is to create reusable components - eg historyService, that can be reused in all other Repositories as opposed to implement it all over again in every Repository. I just quickly ran through the last two links - it seems as just some rant.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer of my own question:

I think if the services will NEVER need to work with certain parts of an aggregate, then the Repository can take care of those aggregate parts instead of relying on calls from the Service to do so. The question then becomes: how much is "User History" married to "User". So much that it would never need a Service acting on it independently?

Answer (score 0):

What 'business concerns' are you talking about when your examples shows a lack of any? In both cases it's just n-tier CRUD. In both cases the UserService is pointless class which just redirects atcions to another class.

You're saying "it can become difficult in a project to know when we are dealing with business concerns as opposed to data persistence concerns". It's rather a sign that you don't need DDD. In projects that really needs DDD, the difference is obvious: all create, read, update, delete and synonyms of previous 4 are persistence concerns.

In your domain, those business concerns might be: user signed up for a newsletter, user visited something, buy something. Think about business tasks that are actually performed, not how you would map it to tables.

Comment: Yes, the user service needs to do more than just call a single repo. I should have had more code there. But business concerns are not always easily mapped to persistence concerns.

Comment: There's not a one-to-one relationship between a business concern and a persistence operation.  I may want to "save User" and the persistence is that there is an operation needed to write to the user table. But my application may require that there is an additional write needed to the user history table every time as well. You might say this is like a case of "denormalized" data and the repo's "save user" will need to write to both tables. Or you might say this is a business concern, that I need to call a User repo first, then call a User History repo next.

Comment: Stop thinking about tables, writes. Forget about the database completely. It's NOT a business concern. Start thinking about behavior. DDD doesn't stand for Data-Dealing Design. When your entities, aggregates and services will be ready (when they will behave correctly) then you can start thinking "OK, how am I suppose to persist and retrieve their state?"